# regular expression mobile and landline number

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to have a mobile phone number in this format (021)123-4567 or (027)123-4567 or landline number in this format (04)970-0676. i have a regular expression which does that except it doesn't contain the '-' and the first 3 or 2 digits are wrapped in the curly brackets (027) or (04) character.
what I want also is after the brackets is to have a hypen after the third digit e.g (04)970- < or (027)635- <

this is what I have.

```
(^\([0][2]\d{1}\))(\d{6,8}$)
```

or this one which shows the possible codes and possible number of characters in phone number this one here is what i kinda want except for the hypen is missing.

```
'/^(\((03|04|06|07|09)\)\d{7})|(\((021|022|025|027|028|029)\)\d{6,8})|((0508|0800|0900)\d{5,8})$/'
```

Comment: This is not even close to your question. But did you think of foreign numbers too? It happens quite often that I get frustrated on forms that don't want to accept my number because Norwegian phone numbers are shorter than usual... (Maybe it doesn't apply for you though) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
/^\(0\d{1,2}\)\d{3}-\d{4}$/
```

Regex are worth learning http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: Just a quick question what does \d{6,8} mean

Comment: @KDM \d stands for digit, {6,8} means repeated 6 to 8 times.