# PHP: How to validate UK landline and mobile numbers?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How can I validate UK telephone numbers? I copied the answer from this site, but this answer only accept mobile number. I want to accept both landline and mobile number. Is it possible?

```
            # @reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099177/validating-uk-phone-numbers-in-php

            $telephone = "01752311149"; // not ok.
            $telephone = "07742055388"; // ok.
            $pattern = "/^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$/";

            if (!preg_match($pattern, $telephone))
            {
                $error = true;
                $message.='<error elementid="telephone" message="invalid" />';
            }
```

I have tried with this regex below but it doesn't work at all,

```
#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512810/regular-expression-mobile-and-landline-number
$pattern = "/^\(0\d{1,2}\)\d{3}-\d{4}$/";
```

Comment: I suggest you read and understand how regular expressions work, then modify the mobile-accept number. Note that `+441`, `+442`, `01`, `02` are all valid landline numbers.

Comment: Are you sure this is a good idea? I find nothing more aggravating than a form that won't accept my phone number just because I happen to be a foreigner. As long as you don't actually call it, you can't be any more certain that the number really exists after validation - see `0207 99999999`. Plus next time London restructures its numbering plans again (as it has done three times over the past 25 years), you have to update your regex.

Comment: I suggest you look at `libphonenumber` - it's an open-source library that Google uses in Android for validating and formatting phone numbers.

Comment: thanks for the tips. I need the validation on a browser only. no android or apple. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's a selection of regular expressions for validating phone numbers at [Regular Expressions for Validating and Formatting GB Telephone Numbers](http://www.aa-asterisk.org.uk/index.php/Regular_Expressions_for_Validating_and_Formatting_GB_Telephone_Numbers):

Alternatively, there's one at [RegExLib.com](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=2632&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) that seems to work well:

```
^((\(44\))( )?|(\(\+44\))( )?|(\+44)( )?|(44)( )?)?((0)|(\(0\)))?( )?(((1[0-9]{3})|(7[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2})|(20)( )?[7-8]{1})( )?([0-9]{3}[ -]?[0-9]{3})|(2[0-9]{2}( )?[0-9]{3}[ -]?[0-9]{4}))$
```

**Edit:**

This  will allow mobile, landline, and special service numbers (999, 123, etc.) -- assumes that spaces have been stripped:

`'/^(?>(?>\+44|0)(?>(?!7624)(?>[12389]\d|5[56]|7[06])\d{8}|(?>(?>[58]00|1\d{2})\d{6})|(?>8001111|845464\d)|7(?>[45789]\d{8}|624\d{6}))|999|112|100|101|111|116|123|155|118\d{3}|(?>\+44|0)(?>800111|8454647))$/D'`

Comment: Have you remembered to add delimeters? E.g. `/` at the start and end?

Comment: yes i did. and it accepts any number including '00000000000'. I dont want to accept '00000000000'....

Comment: Ah, sorry, I copied the basic validation. They have a more thorough one as well which I've switched into my answer.

Comment: thanks. but I think I am using this pattern. it seems to be working as I wanted - `$pattern = "/^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)|\(?01\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$/";`

Comment: I know this is super old, but just in case anyone stumbles across this and tries to use it; the regex in the latest edit is invalid, the first occurrence of `(?>` seems to be wrong. Removing this seems to make it work, but I'm a total noob at regex so I might be missing something important. Also, 3 characters isn't enough to edit otherwise I'd change this myself

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off using an existing library, rather than trying your own validation, as rules are somewhat complex and likely to change with time.

For example, this [PHP version](https://github.com/davideme/libphonenumber-for-PHP) of Google's [libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/):

```php
$phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();
try {
    $numberProto = $phoneUtil->parse('02012345678', 'GB');
} catch (NumberParseException $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

Then you can check the validity of the number with:

```php
$phoneUtil->isValidNumber($numberProto);
```

Furthermore, this library allows you to detect the phone number type (fixed line, mobile, voip, etc.)

Comment: This class is still being updated on github, very useful - https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php